# Can I see my score without killing myself?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Today I completed an enjoyable challenge - slaying the Ender Dragon on hardcore mode!

[image: Ender Dragon]

Since beating him, I know I have a rather large score - I'd really like to see what it is! Is there *any* way to be able to see my score without having to end up like this?

[image]

Comment: I thought the score was just the xp collected (IIRC°

Comment: According to the Wiki, `When the Player dies, a score is displayed on the death screen. This score is exactly the same to the amount of XP the player gathered during their life.` So I'd say @ratchetfreak is correct.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Get [Minecraft Forge](http://files.minecraftforge.net/) and [IngameInfo](http://www.minecraftforum.net/topic/1009577-151-daftpvfs-mods-treecapitator-ingameinfo-crystalwing-startinginv-floatingruins/) then add `Score: &e<score>` somewhere in `.minecraft/config/mod_ingameinfo.cfg` and you'll be able to see your score without dying.

Answer (score 2):

Use NBTExplorer to open `.minecraft/saves/<world_name>/players/<player_name>.dat` and view the `Score` data.

[image]